# VBA Collection: Can get collection property, but cannot loop through it. Error: 'Object is no longer valid'

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to load a collection with values:

```
coll.Add rsSql.Fields(0)
```

But when I try to access the values, I get the error: 'Object is no longer valid'

I can get a collection property, such as `.Count`:

```
MsgBox coll.Count 'Outputs correctly
```

But when I try to loop through the collectionusing either:

```
Dim i
For Each i In coll
    MsgBox i
Next i
''or
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To coll.Count
    MsgBox coll(i)
Next i
```

I get the error above.

I cannot even get the item direct reference. Same error:

```
MsgBox coll(1)
```

Comment: Try setting it to a string variable first: `Dim s As String` - `s = rsSql.Fields(0)` - `coll.Add s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Cast the value as string before adding it to the collection.

Comment: The way you were doing it was adding a reference to the recordset instead of the value of the field.

Comment: I see. I was used to loading recordset fields straight to things like a listbox in a userform, so I understood the value coming in was whatever the field datatype was at the source.

Comment: With listboxes, you can only add strings/values (not objects), so it uses the field's default value. A collection can accept object variables (not just strings), so it uses that instead of the default value.

Comment: Pretty sure you could also do something like this: `coll.Add rsSql.Fields(0).Value` or `coll.Add rsSql.Fields(0) & ""`